Conceptual understanding of steady states in a closed system of water flowing due to a temperature gradient
I have attached a modification of Stommel's two box model. The simplification (linear approximation) of the equation of state has me worried that I do not have a full conceptual understanding. I feel it glosses over the physics, and I want to make sure my reasoning below is at least scientifically sound.
$T_{1}^{*}$ and $T_{2}^{*}$ are the surrounding temperatures separated by a porous wall, and, if no capillary tubes were attached, $T_{1}$ and $T_{2}$ would reach $T_{1}^{*}$ and $T_{2}^{*}$, respectively.
Here are a few questions I have that I need to wrap my head around:

If $T_{1}$ and $T_{2}$ are well-mixed, is the rate of flow in the capillaries proportional to the temperature/density gradient? I know Stommel simplifies the equation of state for density, but am I completely wrong in thinking this? Could this be true in the absence of friction? I ultimately want to undersand this conceptually, but I also want to make sure I am thinking of this in the right way
Here's something I have also been thinking about: If $T_{1}^{*}=35^{o}C$ and $T_{2}^{*}=5^{o}C$, this would mean $T_{1}$ reaches a steady state temperature (slightly?) lower than 35 degrees Celsius, and $T_{2}$ reaches a steady state temperature a bit above 5 degrees Celsius. I would assume there would be a steady state reached for the flow as well. Let's say that now I adjust the surrounding temperature for the colder container to 10 degrees Celsius. So, this means $T_{1}$ reaches a steady state temperature lower than 35 degrees Celsius, and $T_{2}$ reaches a steady state temperature a bit above 10 degrees Celsius. Would the equilibrium flow rate for $T_{1}^{*}=35^{o}C$ and $T_{2}^{*}=5^{o}C$ be larger than for $T_{1}^{*}=35^{o}C$ and $T_{2}^{*}=10^{o}C$? Is this also a way to conceptualize why the water warming at the poles leads to a lower flow rate in the North Atlantic current, for example?


